# How to disable all third-party keyboard in EditText in my own application?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, swift-keyboard

I want to disable all third party keyboard from my application as it is a security concern. Is it possible in Android? If possible, then how can i do it. I want to use only default keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to use only default keyboard" -- there are 25,000+ Android device models. There is no single "default keyboard", and what the default keyboard is for a particular model may be available as a third-party keyboard for others. You are also assuming that the "default keyboard" is not a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, it's not possible to change the keyboard programmatically, unless your application is an IME.